# passing json string as parameter to webmethod

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax post to a webmethod `EmailFormRequestHandler`, I can see on the client side  (through firebug) that status of the request is 200 but it's not hitting the stop point (first line of the webmethod) in my webmethod. Everything was working fine with the json param was an `object` but with the way that I'm deserializing the json I had to change it to a string.

js:

```
function SubmitUserInformation($group) {
    var data = ArrayPush($group);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.com/components/handlers/FormRequestHandler.aspx/EmailFormRequestHandler",
        data: JSON.stringify(data), // returns {"to":"bfleming@allegisgroup.com","from":"bfleming@test.com","message":"sdfasdf"}
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg) {
                $('emailForm-content').hide();
                $('emailForm-thankyou').show();
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            form.data("validator").invalidate(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

aspx:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool EmailFormRequestHandler(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); //stop point set here
    serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });
    dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

    try
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
            new MailAddress(obj.to),
            new MailAddress(obj.from)
        );
        message.Subject = "email test";
        message.Body = "email test body" + obj.message;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"]).Send(message);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: so you are saying the status code is `200` but neither the error nor success callback fires?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the content type in the jQuery JSON post:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

See this article. It helped me greatly when I had a similar issue:

- <s>[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)</s> (*no longer available*)
- *From Internet Archive:* [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20121003163930/http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

You don't need to configure the ScriptManager to EnablePageMethods.

Also, you don't need to deserialize the JSON-serialized object in your WebMethod. Let ASP.NET do that for you. Change the signature of your WebMethod to this (noticed that I appended "Email" to the words "to" and "from" because these are C# keywords and it's a bad practice to name variables or parameters that are the same as a keyword. You will need to change your JavaScript accordingly so the JSON.stringify() will serialize your string correctly:

```
// Expected JSON: {"toEmail":"...","fromEmail":"...","message":"..."}

[WebMethod]
public static bool EmailFormRequestHandler(string toEmail, string fromEmail, string message)
{
    // TODO: Kill this code...
    // var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); //stop point set here
    // serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });
    // dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

    try
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage(
            new MailAddress(toEmail),
            new MailAddress(fromEmail)
        );
        mailMessage.Subject = "email test";
        mailMessage.Body = String.Format("email test body {0}" + message);
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"]).Send(mailMessage);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, (just in case you weren't aware) JSON.stringify() doesn't work in IE7. You will need [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: this is actually what i ended up doing. It's not an ideal solution as it's not really maintainable when i need to add fields. it can quickly get out of control, but it get's the job done for now. Thanks Mario!!

Comment: You're welcome and I agree with you. I haven't tried passing in complex objects, but I think it may be worth giving a shot.

Comment: i actually did that with another web method and asp handles it wonderfully, and of course, much more maintainable :)

Comment: @MarioJVargas hi, i heard usage of post verb is for manipulating with data, db, so explore to find pass in same case data to sever by get request, but i think it's not possible.  is that possible?

Comment: @Mohammadreza , yes, you're right that POST should be used when making changes to data (in the case of REST, you would be adding a new item to your data source). Unfortunately, when using ASP.NET Web Forms WebMethods, you're stuck with making POST requests. GET requests aren't supported. If you're looking for a more RESTful solution, consider [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Comment: Passing the values into the signature was the trick for me.  Sometimes it's too easy. ;)  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, @Jakub, for letting us know. I replaced the link with one from the Internet Archives.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to set a break point?
Don't set that point in firebug. Set that breakpoint in VS itself. Then attach VS to local IIS.

By the way, in your ajax call you set three parameter, your webmethod takes only one. and the parameter name must be the same.

The format of your data attribute in the ajax call is also not good. It should look like this

```
data: '{"to":"bfleming@allegisgroup.com","from":"bfleming@test.com","message":"sdfasdf"}',
```

it should be framed in ' '

Answer (score 0):

May be this code helps someone:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> JsonToDictionary(dynamic request)
{
JObject x = JObject.FromObject(request);
Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (JProperty prop in (JContainer)x)
    { 
       result.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }

return result;
}
```

I use it while debuging when frontend comes first.

Answer (score -1):

First thing I noticed is that you are missing contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" in your $.ajax. Also addd to your $.ajax a complete callback it returns jqXHR,textStatus. I think the complete callback will help because textStatus one of the following ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). This might help you track down the issue.