# Reading the Http POST body content from my web service? (.net 3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

Okay, this is driving me nuts. I'm integrating Amazon SNS into a web service I have. Amazon simply sends an HTTP post with a bunch of json content to the url I specify. I just can't access it.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void HandleBounce()
{
    notification = //I need to put the JSON content into here
}
```

Amazon simply access the url (http://test.com/webservice.aspx/HandleBounce). The method is being called correctly. I just need to get the data it's sending in the post. How do I do that?

EDIT:

I originally tried using

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void HandleBounce(string json)
{
    notification = //I need to put the JSON content into here
}
```

but when I do this, the method is simply never called at all. At least when I remove the parameter, the method is working.

EDIT 2:

This is from the amazon website as to what request they send to me:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
x-amz-sns-message-type: SubscriptionConfirmation
x-amz-sns-message-id: 165545c9-2a5c-472c-8df2-7ff2be2b3b1b
x-amz-sns-topic-arn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic
Content-Length: 1336
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent

{
  "Type" : "SubscriptionConfirmation",
  "MessageId" : "165545c9-2a5c-472c-8df2-7ff2be2b3b1b",
  "Token" : "2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e241d09c805a5a57b30d712f794cc5f6a988666d92768dd60a747ba6f3beb71854e285d6ad02428b09ceece29417f1f02d609c582afbacc99c583a916b9981dd2728f4ae6fdb82efd087cc3b7849e05798d2d2785c03b0879594eeac82c01f235d0e717736",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic",
  "Message" : "You have chosen to subscribe to the topic arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic.\nTo confirm the subscription, visit the SubscribeURL included in this message.",
  "SubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic&Token=2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e241d09c805a5a57b30d712f794cc5f6a988666d92768dd60a747ba6f3beb71854e285d6ad02428b09ceece29417f1f02d609c582afbacc99c583a916b9981dd2728f4ae6fdb82efd087cc3b7849e05798d2d2785c03b0879594eeac82c01f235d0e717736",
  "Timestamp" : "2012-04-26T20:45:04.751Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "EXAMPLEpH+DcEwjAPg8O9mY8dReBSwksfg2S7WKQcikcNKWLQjwu6A4VbeS0QHVCkhRS7fUQvi2egU3N858fiTDN6bkkOxYDVrY0Ad8L10Hs3zH81mtnPk5uvvolIC1CXGu43obcgFxeL3khZl8IKvO61GWB6jI9b5+gLPoBc1Q=",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem"
  }
```

Comment: Make your method take a parameter of type string and call it json. Debug your application and let us know what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing json string as parameter to webmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946695/passing-json-string-as-parameter-to-webmethod)

Comment: @Maritim , I originally tried to do that but it simply won't call the method at all when I have a string parameter. Unfortunately since the request is being sent from Amazon I have no idea what the response is, but I imagine the parameter is not expected or used.

Comment: Do you have any sort of request available which you can inspect? I suspect that maybe the post request's content type is not what you expect.

Comment: @Maritim , I have added the supposed request they send to the main question. I notice they are encoding the type as text, not json. Is there something different I need to do to handle that?

Comment: Attempt to make your method take a string parameter but remove the attribute [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] from your method... then debug your app and retry the request from Amazon to see what happens.

Comment: I removed the ScriptMethod and added in the string parameter. The method is no longer being called after that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following adjustments, I was able to resolve the issue:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void HandleBounce() //This method is called from Amazon Simple Notification Service when we receive a bounce.
    {
        string notification = "";
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
            notification = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```